# iPhone app crashes in device but it is working in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xmppframework

i am working on a chat application .i used XMPP to implement this apps. it is working fine.when i want to restrict the user login in multiple device (same user ) .this is also working in simulator.but when i used device apps crashed and not showing any exception in log window( output window) .but Xcode control reached on that point

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:

0x39f07b20:  cbz    r0, 0x39f07b5e            ; objc_msgSend + 62
0x39f07b22:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x39f07b26:  ldrh.w r12, [r9, #12]
0x39f07b2a:  ldr.w  r9, [r9, #8]
0x39f07b2e:  and.w  r12, r12, r1
0x39f07b32:  add.w  r9, r9, r12, lsl #3
0x39f07b36:  ldr.w  r12, [r9]
0x39f07b3a:  teq.w  r12, r1
0x39f07b3e:  bne    0x39f07b46                ; objc_msgSend + 38
0x39f07b40:  ldr.w  r12, [r9, #4]
0x39f07b44:  bx     r12
0x39f07b46:  cmp.w  r12, #1
0x39f07b4a:  blo    0x39f07b58                ; objc_msgSend + 56
0x39f07b4c:  it     eq
0x39f07b4e:  ldreq.w r9, [r9, #4]
0x39f07b52:  ldr    r12, [r9, #8]!
0x39f07b56:  b      0x39f07b3a                ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x39f07b58:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x39f07b5c:  b      0x39f07da0                ; _objc_msgSend_uncached
0x39f07b5e:  mov.w  r1, #0
0x39f07b62:  bx     lr
0x39f07b64:  nop    
0x39f07b66:  nop    
0x39f07b68:  nop    
0x39f07b6a:  nop    
0x39f07b6c:  nop    
0x39f07b6e:  nop    
0x39f07b70:  nop    
0x39f07b72:  nop    
0x39f07b74:  nop    
0x39f07b76:  nop    
0x39f07b78:  nop    
0x39f07b7a:  nop    
0x39f07b7c:  nop    
0x39f07b7e:  nop  

  i don't know what is the problem .can some one help to solve this issue
```

Comment: not very helpful. Enable NSZombies and add an exception breakpoint for all exceptions.

Comment: i have used breakpoint but not able to trace the issue

Comment: Hi! I've got the same eschew, and even stack is absolutely the same! I think that happens in my app because i use XCDYouTubeKit. Have you solved your problem? If so, how?

Comment: yes i solved.@serg_ov

Comment: post yourapp crashes @serg_ov

Comment: Here's my topic. But now i'm not shore is that because of video player or what... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034938/ios-app-crashes-from-time-to-time-when-try-to-play-video?noredirect=1#comment38941746_25034938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a memory usage issue because the simulator uses the memory of your computer that is more powerful than the device. I suggest you to run your application using Instruments to see the allocations and find a clue of how to fix it or analyze your code, making changes to save memory. Check also if your app, in some moment receives memory warnings.

Hope it helps you.