# iOS: app crashes from time to time when try to play video

Tags: ios, video, crash

Please, anybody, help me! I'm using `XCDYouTubeKit` to implement video playback from youtube. Here is my code:

```
self.videoPlayerVC = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier: videoID];
[self.videoPlayerVC presentInView: self.videoContainerView];
[self.videoPlayerVC.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

I have got 2 problems with it:

1) From time to time in the container where the app should be displayed only the white screen is shown, therefor the sound can be heard. UI responses touches.

2) From time to time app crashes after the first picture of video loaded (if xcode freezes the app the sound of video can be heard).

The error is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0xc)
```

The main stack:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x3af10620:  cbz    r0, 0x3af1065e            ; objc_msgSend + 62
0x3af10622:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x3af10626:  ldrh.w r12, [r9, #12]       <---Here it crashes
0x3af1062a:  ldr.w  r9, [r9, #8]
0x3af1062e:  and.w  r12, r12, r1
0x3af10632:  add.w  r9, r9, r12, lsl #3
0x3af10636:  ldr.w  r12, [r9]
0x3af1063a:  teq.w  r12, r1
0x3af1063e:  bne    0x3af10646                ; objc_msgSend + 38
0x3af10640:  ldr.w  r12, [r9, #4]
0x3af10644:  bx     r12
0x3af10646:  cmp.w  r12, #0x1
0x3af1064a:  blo    0x3af10658                ; objc_msgSend + 56
0x3af1064c:  it     eq
0x3af1064e:  ldreq.w r9, [r9, #4]
0x3af10652:  ldr    r12, [r9, #8]!
0x3af10656:  b      0x3af1063a                ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x3af10658:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x3af1065c:  b      0x3af108a0                ; _objc_msgSend_uncached
0x3af1065e:  mov.w  r1, #0x0
0x3af10662:  bx     lr
0x3af10664:  nop    
0x3af10666:  nop    
0x3af10668:  nop    
0x3af1066a:  nop    
0x3af1066c:  nop    
0x3af1066e:  nop    
0x3af10670:  nop    
0x3af10672:  nop    
0x3af10674:  nop    
0x3af10676:  nop    
0x3af10678:  nop    
0x3af1067a:  nop    
0x3af1067c:  nop    
0x3af1067e:  nop
```

And that on UIAplicationMain

```
0x330007f2:  mov    r0, r5
0x330007f4:  blx    0x335c3d50                ; symbol stub for: CFRunLoopSourceSignal$shim
0x330007f8:  b      0x33000842                ; UIApplicationMain + 1090
0x330007fa:  movw   r0, #0xf172
0x330007fe:  movt   r0, #0x8b2
0x33000802:  add    r0, pc
0x33000804:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x33000806:  mov    r0, r11
0x33000808:  blx    0x335c3d50                ; symbol stub for: CFRunLoopSourceSignal$shim
0x3300080c:  movw   r1, #0xf264
0x33000810:  movt   r1, #0x8b2
0x33000814:  add    r1, pc
0x33000816:  ldr    r1, [r1]
0x33000818:  blx    0x335c3d50                ; symbol stub for: CFRunLoopSourceSignal$shim
0x3300081c:  movw   r1, #0xf2b8
0x33000820:  movt   r1, #0x8b2
0x33000824:  add    r1, pc
0x33000826:  ldr    r1, [r1]
0x33000828:  blx    0x335c3d50                ; symbol stub for: CFRunLoopSourceSignal$shim
0x3300082c:  mov    r2, r0
0x3300082e:  movw   r0, #0xf898
0x33000832:  movt   r0, #0x8b2
0x33000836:  movs   r3, #0x1
0x33000838:  add    r0, pc
0x3300083a:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x3300083c:  mov    r0, r5
0x3300083e:  blx    0x335c3d50                ; symbol stub for: CFRunLoopSourceSignal$shim
0x33000842:  movw   r0, #0xf0a6
0x33000846:  movt   r0, #0x8b2
0x3300084a:  add    r0, pc
0x3300084c:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x3300084e:  ldr    r0, [sp, #0x14]
0x33000850:  blx    0x335c3d50                ; symbol stub for: CFRunLoopSourceSignal$shim
0x33000854:  movw   r0, #0xf870
0x33000858:  movt   r0, #0x8b2
0x3300085c:  movw   r2, #0x431e
0x33000860:  movt   r2, #0x8b7
0x33000864:  add    r0, pc
0x33000866:  add    r2, pc
0x33000868:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x3300086a:  ldr    r0, [r2]
0x3300086c:  blx    0x335c3d50                ; symbol stub for: CFRunLoopSourceSignal$shim
0x33000870:  movs   r0, #0x0           <------ Here it crashes
0x33000872:  add    sp, #0x18
0x33000874:  pop.w  {r8, r10, r11}
0x33000878:  pop    {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
0x3300087a:  nop    
0x3300087c:  mov    r8, r8
0x3300087e:  mov    r8, r8
```

Comment: Did you check if the videoContainerView is allocated and initialized ?

Comment: @Paulo i'm not shore what that means for me - I'm using interface builder and that self.videoContainerView is just an IBOutlet to the view in IB witch is not initialized in code. May be that is an issue? How and when should i allocate and initialize it?

Comment: IB would normally allocate and initialise the objects in it ready to use but code can always mess up the allocation.   Bad access is usually an allocation or init or usage issue,  Let me do some checks and get back to you, Something about presenting a view controller in a view does not sound right. but I'll check first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you trying to help me! I use XCDYouTubeKit framework and the above code is provided buy them. I think the problem is the other. The above code is called from viewDidLoad, may be that is a problem?

Comment: checked XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController you are just using the default code and it worked out fine,  Check videoID to see if it is an allocated and initialised NSString

Comment: You can do a step by step debug in Xcode, and it will tell you if the variables are allocated or not just put a breakpoint before your code and go though is step by step, I have a feeling that its your variable for the videoID

Comment: Nope, that's correct. Id is fetched from core data so  that is not an eschew. More detail on problem: i've got a DetailView, inside witch there is a view for video display. So when the DetailView receives viewDidLoad it calls it's own method with the code above. May be when viewDidLoad is called the view of video still not allocated/initialized?

Comment: If you used IB properly, all the objects are allocated and initialised by the time it gets to viewDidLoad. The best tool to use for these problems is to do a step by step debug in Xcode pay attention to the variable addresses if one of the variable address is low values x'00000'  it is not allocated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58363/discussion-between-serg-ov-and-paulo).